# Accessing array index variable from bash shell script loop

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I want to access the array index variable while looping thru an array in my bash shell script.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
for i in ${AR[*]}; do
  echo $i
done
```

The result of the above script is:

```
foo
bar
baz
bat
```

The result I seek is:

```
0
1
2
3
```

How do I alter my script to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one character:

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
for i in ${!AR[*]}; do                                                                  ←
  echo "$i"
done
```

(Add an exclamation mark (`!`) to the array expansion:
`${!AR[*]}`.)  From the man page:

> **Parameter Expansion**
>
>   ︙
>   ${!
>   *name*
>   [@]}
>   ${!
>   *name*
>   [*]}
>     **List of array keys.**
>     If
>     *name*
>     is an array variable,
>       expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in
>     *name*
>     . 
>       If
>     *name*
>     is not an array,
>       expands to 0 if
>     *name*
>     is set and null otherwise. 
>       When
>     `@`
>     is used and the expansion appears within double quotes,
>       each key expands to a separate word.